# How to prove force is conservative?

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, conservation-laws, work, conservative-field

How do I prove whether a force perpendicular to the motion is conservative and $\mathbf{F}=\mathbf{F_{0}}\sin(at)$ conservative, where $\mathbf{F_{0}}$ is a constant vector.

I knew that for a force to be conservative, it's $\nabla \times \mathbf{F}=0$ everywhere or the work done around a closed path without including origin should be zero.

*Self-learning from Kleppner and Kolenkow's book.*

Comment: Why would you exclude the origin?

Comment: @mikuszefski : Let me define a force $F=\frac{A}{r}\hat{\theta}$, if I calculate the work done around a closed path including origin is $W=A(\theta_{2}-\theta_{1})=2\pi A$, which is not equal to zero.

Comment: The Force $F=F_{0}\sin(at)$ is not even a vector as it's written, can you please be more specific? With $\nabla XF=0$ do you mean $\nabla \times \mathbf{F}=0$?

Comment: @Rumplestillskin: It is the information that I have, this question is from Kleppner's CM book.

Comment: @AlessandroZunino: $F_{0}$ is a constant vector as given in the question.  It's $\nabla \times F = 0$, am new to latex, I've edited it.

Comment: @Rumplestillskin Conservative doesn't mean conserved, so what you have written has nothing to do with the question.
To Gopal: a vector is usually denoted with a bold character $\mathbf{F}$ or with an arrow $\vec{F}$, otherwise it's considered a scalar. Anyway, what is $t$? Just a parameter? Because in this case is trivial to prove that $\nabla \times \mathbf{F}=0$

Comment: @AlessandroZunino ahhh of course I need to read more carefully. I was wondering why we were talking about work!!! My bad!

Comment: @AlessandroZunino: 't' is not defined in the book. What if we take 't' as time.

Comment: If $t$ is time, then the force does not depend on the position, then all the derivatives are zero and its trivial to say that $\nabla \times \mathbf{F}=0$.

Comment: Your example above is non-zero, because it is non-conservative. Still no reason to exclude the origin.

Comment: @mikuszefski: you mean, it doesn't matter where you take, if work done around a loop is zero, the it's conservative?

Comment: Well, I guess one would say: If the work around every possible closed loop is zero, it is conservative....that's sort of what the $\mathbf {rot}$ operator is doing.

Comment: A properly conservative force cannot depend on time, it can only depend on position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a force is perpendicular to the motion then $\mathbf{F}\cdot \dot{\mathbf{x}}=0 \quad\forall t$, then the work

$$ W=\oint_\ell \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{x}=0$$

So it's conservative.

---

If $t$ is time, then the force does not depend on the position, then all the derivatives are zero and its trivial to say that $\nabla \times \mathbf{F}=0$.

Comment: Does this mean viscous force is not conservative?

Comment: Tipically all the friction/dumping forces are not conservative.